# How to use rownum in mysql

Tags: mysql, django, paging

In my case, I try to use this code for pa

```
boardList = DjangoBoard.objects.raw('SELECT Z.* FROM(SELECT X.*, ceil( rownum / %s ) as page FROM ( SELECT ID,SUBJECT,NAME, CREATED_DATE, MAIL,MEMO,HITS \
                                    FROM web_DJANGOBOARD  ORDER BY ID DESC ) X ) Z WHERE page = %s', [rowsPerPage, current_page])
```

But, It's Oracle's code, Not for mysql. So, rownum has error. How can I do?

Comment: did you search on mysql rownum or rank ?

Comment: There are like a boatload of examples with variables to mimic rownum